# How to use my own plugin into an existing eclipse tool

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I used to develope my own plugins to add some funcionalities to an existing eclipse tool. I just used to add my plugin (jar file) into the plugin folder's tool and it contributed fine adding my own menus into the tool but it's not working anymore since they migrated.

The eclipse tool migrated from 3.x version to some hibrid between 3.x and 4.x. My old plugin used extentions to contribute menus. I tried a test plugin with e4 but it seems like if the eclipse tool is not reading anymore the plugin folder when I drop my plugin there... I cannot modify the eclipse tool, just try to add my own plugins to contribute with the application. Could somebody give a hand with it?

Comment: There should be a 'dropins' folder that you can put the plugin in. Eclipse will look there the next time it starts.

Comment: It is not an application that I'm building in eclipse, it's an existing tool (Talend) for which I created some plugins and after export them I just used to drop them into the plugins folder and Talend use to show me the changes after restart. There was never a dropin folder.

Comment: If it is not Eclipse but a tool based on Eclipse it will depend on exactly what plugins are included in that tool. You will have to ask the tool vendor.

Comment: Thanks greg-449, I'm already asking them to figure out what is happening.